# Wordpress Contact Form 7 integration WP Webhook is not working

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, contact-form-7

I am developing a Wordpress website. Especially integrating an existing Wordpress website with a Webhook/ API. Literally, making a post request when a form is submitted. I am using this plugin, https://wprookies.com/contact-form-7-webhooks/. I installed it on a local Wordpress Website and tested it. The data are sent to the other website through webhook when a form is submitted. I tried to configure it on a website that is up and running online using the same settings.

This is the Form tab of Contact Form 7.

```
<label> First Name (required)
    [text* firstname] </label>

<label> Surname (required)
    [text* surname] </label>

<label> Phone Number
    [text* phone] </label>

<label> Email
    [text* email] </label>

<label> Marketing GDPR
    [text* marketing-gdpr] </label>

[submit "Send"]
```

This is the screenshot of the Webhook Settings tab of contact form 7

[image]

When I submit the form on the front end, the form is submitted successfully, but no data is sent through webhook. I tested using the same settings on another wordpress project which is installed on my local machine. Everything is working fine. Any clue of why it is happening? I just can't think of where to starting digging.

Comment: Check the server settings. If the plugin uses cURL check whether it is enabled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check it by deactivate another plugin and still it not working then check it with another theme. This is not working might be due to conflict with another plugin or theme function.